# MySQL/Rails Version Control for CMS - How is it usually done?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, version-control

How do projects like [BrowserCMS](http://www.browsercms.org/) for Rails implement version control for a CMS?  What is best practice for version control with database content?  How does it relate to git/svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely certain if this is what you are asking but there are a lot of solutions that use activerecord model level versioning.

Vestal Versions, acts_as_versioned, has_versions, acts_as_revisable....

It's a crowded plugin space..here is the [ruby toolbox listing](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_versioning.html).